# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:30.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, androidx, appcompatactivity

**It Shows:**
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:30.0.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

build.gradle(:app):

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.0'
}
```

Comment: The support libraries v30 **don't exist**.

Comment: Start using `AndroidX` artifact of libraries .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `androidx` library mostly you need to use this now:

To use this you need to add `Androidx` support to your project if it is not migrated to `Androidx`.

You can find here how to migrate project to [Androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

or use the last `support library`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

It is because the `support libraries` you trying to use don't exist.

For Add `Google Maven repository` and `google()` do this inside `build.gradle` which outside of app directory.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
     
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Yes , it will going to download that dependencies add that required things and sync.

Comment: I did but still ,
Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Comment: For that you need to add maven repository inside *build.gradle* which is outside of app dir. check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The support libraries v30 **don't exist**.
Remove them.

Use the [androidx libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings):

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

To use them you have to add the `google()` repo in your top-level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying: Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.2.0/appcompat-1.2.0.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :app

Comment: @AudoTravel you have to add the google() repo in your buil.gradle file

Comment: It's already or i don't understand, Could you please check: 
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: @AudoTravel I've updated the answer. You have to add the `google()` repo in the `allprojects` block

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i'm still getting errors such as: This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.